# Problems starting autossh on boot [ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to automatically start an SSH tunnel to my server on boot from a ubuntu box. I have an ubuntu box that's mounted on an 18-wheeler and is networked behind an air card. The box hosts a mysql database that i'm trying to have replicated when the aircard is connected. As I can never be sure of my IP and how many or which routers I'm behind I'm connected to my replication server with an SSH tunnel. I got that working using the following command:

```
ssh -R 3307:localhost:3307 myuser@myserver.com
```

Now I'd like that to start whenever the box is, and be alive all the time, so I installed auto-ssh and setup this little script:

```
ID=xkenneth
HOST=erdosmiller.com
AUTOSSH_POLL=15
AUTOSSH_PORT=20000
AUTOSSH_GATETIME=30
AUTOSSH_DEBUG=yes
AUTOSSH_PATH=/usr/bin/ssh
export AUTOSSH_POLL AUTOSSH_DEBUG AUTOSSH_PATH AUTOSSH_GATETIME AUTOSSH_PORT
autossh -2 -fN -M 20000 -R 3307:localhost:3306 ${ID}@${HOST}
```

I've tried putting this scrip in /etc/init.d/ and using a post-up command in /etc/network/interfaces as well as putting it in /etc/network/if-up.d/. In both situations the script starts on boot, but the tunnel doesn't appear to be correctly established. The script works when run manually.

Answer (score 1):

If it is running properly but not connecting, I would suspect that it is getting ahead of itself and not waiting until the network is connected. Try delaying the tunnel by adding a sleep at the beginning of the script. `sleep 60` would probably do the job, not sure how fast your connection establishes.

I suspect this since autossh gives up if the first attempt is not successful. From the README:

```
If the ssh session fails with an exit status of 1 on the very first 
try, autossh will assume that there is some problem with syntax or
the connection setup, and will exit rather than retrying;
```

Note that it also says you can set `AUTOSSH_GATETIME` to 0 to disable that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the script, do you enter the password manually? If so, you'll have to set up paswordless login using SSH keys.

Comment: Hi Hayalci, I've generated the keys so it's passwordless.